# Visual Studio 2015 & GIT - Overwrite remote repository with local staging

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I have a Visual Studio Solution on Visual Studio 2015 that is not connected to GIT.

It has a local repository manually created with `git init` command but in Visual Studio the git features are not initilized ( i can't do right click-> commit for example and I can't see checked out files ).

What I want to do is this:

1. Add all files of the solution to the GIT staging
2. Connect to the remote repository
3. Clean the remote repository ( in this moment contains only a file )
4. Push all local staging to remote repository

What are the correct steps to do that ? ( by command line or by visual studio )

In this moment the visual studio solution folder contains .git folder after that I run `git init` but Visual Studio is used just like a file editor...

If I try do do "File -> ADD Solution to Source Control" nothing happens, no window is open...

Thanks to support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clone the repository on your computer: `git clone <url> <directory>`
2. copy your files into the clone directory
3. commit your files: `git add <files>`, `git commit -m"<message>"`
4. push your changes: `git push`.

If you want to remove the file in the repository, delete it and commit that.

If you *really* want to purge the file from repository history:

1. run `git init` in your project directory
2. add your repository as a new remote: `git remote add origin <url>`
3. commit your files: `git add <files>`, `git commit -m"<message>"`
4. force push your changes to origin: `git push origin master`

Comment: Can you provide me the git command of the first 4 point ? (thanks)

Comment: Your solution helped me to do what I needed.
This link was also very usefull to help me in my task: https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2016/07/21/step-by-step-working-with-github-repository-and-visual-studio-2015.aspx